# PHP find a remote absolute path

Tags: php, image, path, absolute

I'm having a problem fetching the absolute URL of a remote image. What I'm doing right now is this:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $e){
$path = parse_url($e->src, PHP_URL_PATH);
$absolute = realpath($path);
    if($e->src==$path){
    echo '<img class="pic" src=' . $absolute . '/><br/>';
    }

}
```

This code has been written using the simple html dom project. The ideea is that I can't display images with a relative url in the original coding because they are not located on my server.

So does anyone know how to resolve the absolute path of a remote image?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by the absolute path of a remote URL.  You can't reference remote files using absolute paths.  You will need to use the standard **http://www.path.com/to/file.jpg** returned by **$e->src**

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to grab the base domain, along with the relative url root.

So, if the image was found on the page, yoursite.com/slideshow/4/view, but was relatively pointing to ./../../images/435.jpg, you would just combine the paths.

Otherwise, if the image pointed to the root of the domains (you can use regex to find if the first character is a /), then you can get use just yoursite.com and add that path to the string.

Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php to parse the url into the site host, the relative page to that host.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the address of where you are filtering these images, why not just add that to what the src property returns?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this a lot (like an entire site) you might look at the power that behind wget.

One of the options is to rebuild urls, IIRC.

-k
--convert-links

Might be worth your time taking a look at [wget](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_wget.htm).